# using postgreSQL and jsondb in the same web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

My site is written in ruby (rails) and it's very easy to persist the results of an offsite json feed with using jsondb, so I have an app that would benefit from this, but I think I'd like to keep the rest of the site running on postgrs

Would I be better off moving everything to one database (jsondb?) or does rails easily allow me to use multiple ORM's in the same app

```
# just notes, ignore if you like cos the answers are subjective
# Perhaps I should build two web apps?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is practical to use multiple databases.

I'd take a hard look at the **[tenacity](http://johnpwood.net/2011/01/05/introducing-tenacity-an-orm-independent-way-to-manage-inter-database-relationships/)** gem, which was introduced recently as a way to manage multiple databases within Rails .. and even relationships between them.

It doesn't look like it currently supports **jsondb**, but given its architecture, it should be possible to write your own adapter (... and then contribute it back?)

Comment: thanks this is great, i will have a play around with it - I'm fairly sure it's going to sovle the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

It's really better to have only one database. If it's better to use postGresql use it or only jsondb.

Having more than one database can be complicated to understand where is really your data.